# Python finding string between 2 tags

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to read content between 2 tags stored in a file, content may span in multiple lines. Tag can occur 0 or 1 time in the file.

For example: File content can be

```
title:Corruption Today: Corruption today in
content:Corruption Today: 
Corruption today in 
score:0.91750675
```

So, while reading "Content:" , my query should result "Corruption Today: Corruption today in".
After some googling I am able to write following code

```
myfile = open(files,'r');
filecontent = myfile.read();

startPtrs = [m.start()+8 for m in re.finditer('content:', filecontent)];
startPtr = startPtrs[0];
endPtrs = [m.start()-1 for m in re.finditer('score:', filecontent)];
endPtr = endPtrs[0];

content = filecontent[startPtr:endPtr];
```

I am not sure how efficient above code is as we are iterating through filecontent 2 times to retrieve the content. Can something more efficient can be done.

Comment: Is this the whole file? or for example `content` can appear several times?

Comment: What is a 'tag'? Does every line that includes a colon `:` have a tag?

Comment: @KobiK : As specified above a tag can occur 0 or 1 time. So either "content:" is there or not there.

Comment: @LutzHorn : Yes every line with a : have a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find a string beetwen 2 substrings you can use `re` moudle:

```
import re

myfile = open(files,'r');
filecontent = myfile.read();

results = re.compile('content(.*?)score', re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE).findall(filecontent)
print results
```

Some explanation:

`IGNORECASE` from docs:

> Perform case-insensitive matching; expressions like [A-Z] will match lowercase letters, too. This is not affected by the current locale.

`DOTALL`  from Docs:

```
(Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character except a newline. If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any character including a newline.
```

`Compile` you can see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile)

Also there are some other solutions you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3368991/1982962)