# extract what is between two words in a line

Tags: python-2.7

If I have this line

```
"he is a good man and he goes every day to a school"
```

And I want to detect what is between the two words "he""and", so the output will be

```
is a good man
```

I tried this

```
for line in file:
    print line[line.index('he'): line.index('and')]
```

This code gives the output

```
he is a good man
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the command `re.search()`:

```
import re
s = "he is a good man and he goes every day to a school"
result = re.search('he (.*) and', s)
                    #^-------^ Find string in between 'he' and 'and'

print result.group(1)
```

This outputs:

```
>>> 
is a good man
>>>
```

---

Also, if you don't fancy the `re` module, there are many other methods to do this.

Please have a look here: [Find string between two substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368969/find-string-between-two-substrings)

Answer (score 0):

Slice is start/from index **inclusive** and finish/to index **exclusive**. This is why it excludes 'and' but includes 'he'

```
for line in file:
    print line[line.index('he') - 1: line.index('and')]
```