# Print string between two variable substrings

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for the following:

```
dna = '**atg**abcdefghijk**tga**aa'

start = 'atg'

stop = 'tag' or 'taa' or 'tga'
```

I would like to get all the characters between start and stop. I have tried with:

```
print (dna.find(start:stop))
```

but it keeps me saying that the ":" are invalid syntax.

Comment: Well, yeah. That's not how you call find. Also, I don't think find does what you think it does. I suspect you want slicing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find string between two substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368969/find-string-between-two-substrings)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to help find any suitable matches as follows:

```
import re

dna = 'atgabcdefghijktgaaa'
start = 'atg'
stop = ['tag', 'taa', 'tga']

print re.findall(r'{}(.*?)(?:{})'.format(start, '|'.join(stop)), dna)
```

This would display the following:

```
['abcdefghijk']
```