# Python2.7/ NLTK remove part of string before certain character

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

I am reading a csv file, containing 371 lines of text.

> 0þ"Text including numbers and quotes"þ4.6

I am trying to extract the texting between the þ" and "þ. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368969/find-string-between-two-substrings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all!

Both your responses helped me find the solution:

```
test = sent[(sent.index('þ"')):(sent.index('"þ'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'þ"|"þ' '{print $2}' data.csv
```

The above command prints the 2nd column of each row in the file `data.csv`,
where columns are separated by either a `þ"` OR a `"þ`.