# Declaring a stopping position when extracting multiple substrings in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, parsing, substring

I am new to python and am trying to parse a long text string for sub-strings between two exact patterns.  The problem lies in telling python to stop at the first occurrence of the end pattern.  I also need to collect all instances of the sub-strings into place them into an array storage to be used later on.  I am trying to utilize the (re) module example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368969/find-string-between-two-substrings) by Nikolaus Gradwohl for simplicity. Below is an example of what I have done.

```
import re
string='valuepattern1":"capture",abcdpattern1":"capture2",defg'
result = re.search('pattern1":"(.*)",', string)
print result.group(1)

Output: capture",abcdpattern1":"capture2"
```

Here I am trying to collect every instance of capture (capture and capture2) found in the string between the set beginning point of (pattern1":") and the immediate ending point (",) after capture.  Each instance collected needs to be added to an array, as shown below.

```
print result
Output: [capture,capture2]
```

Note that capture does not have a set length and varies all throughout the string, however, the beginning and ending patterns remain consistent through the string.

Thank you in advance for any help on this matter.

Comment: Is this input supposed to be JSON or part of a larger JSON string? Python has a JSON parser. Even if it's not JSON, it looks like the kind of thing where regex parsing could be quite fragile.

Comment: Thank you for the information @user2357112 .  The string is a compacted JSON file.  I've been trying to convert old scripts done in bash, by a previous student, to that of python.  A majority of their script contains regex commands which I am not partial to, nor of which I like as it is impractical in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the pattern so that the `.` in the capturing group doesn't match the closing quotation mark. I can see two reasonable ways to do it:

First, you could use a non-greedy wildcard: `pattern1":"(.*?)"`. The `*?` tells it to match the smallest possible number of characters, rather than the largest possible number.

The second option is to use a character class to exclude quotation marks from the captured part of the pattern: `pattern1":"([^"]*)"` Using a `^` as the first character in the brackets tells it to exclude the rest of the characters, so `[^"]` is any non-quotation-mark character.

Comment: If you haven't done a lot of regex work before, Python's implementation isn't the kindest. I've found [Pythex](http://pythex.org/) to be incredibly helpful when I haven't done one in a while and if you test the solution by @Blckknght you'll see just what changes when you use a non-greedy regex.

Comment: Thank you both for the information and assistance on the matter.  The Pythex site will be very useful for future practice.