# Finding a price value inside a unicode text

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I'd like to extract multiple price values from a unicode text which may have multiple currencies and prefixes right before the value itself. Possible situations are:

```
An apple costs: 1,01 €
2€ for an apple
The $1.21 apple
...
```

So the most likely prefixes are `whitespace, €/$/etc, \n` and a whitespace is mostly closing the range of the value.

There are a bunch of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3369000/3191334) about finding a string between two other strings - unfortunately nothing worked for me yet, like this:

```
result = re.findall(r'\s+(.*?)€\s', lowerCaseDescrip, re.DOTALL)
```

Maybe using `re` isn't the best solution for this situation?

Comment: I suggested a duplicate.  Although it doesn't search for € as a suffix or a comma separator, your code above convinces me that you can make those adaptations.

Comment: It looks like in your example that  `€` can only be a **postfix** of the price, `$` is however a **prefix**

Comment: Thanks and sorry! Yes it's duplicate.