# Python: Find a string between two strings, repeatedly

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm new to Python and still learning about regular expressions, so this question may sound trivial to some regex expert, but here you go.
I suppose my question is a generalization of [this question about finding a string between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368969/find-string-between-two-substrings). I wonder: what if this pattern (initial_substring + substring_to_find + end_substring) is repeated many times in a long string?
For example

```
test='someth1 var="this" someth2 var="that" '
result= re.search('var=(.*) ', test)
print result.group(1)
>>> "this" someth2 var="that"
```

Instead, I'd like to get a list like `["this","that"]`.
How can I do it?

Comment: does it have to be `regex`?

Comment: That was the idea, but if there's a more sensible way to do it, please do!

Comment: @Nonancourt - there isn't, in almost any case regex will be the fastest and most 'readable' way to do it. Sure, you can do manual string search but you'd need to have a really good reason to go down that path.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis how were you thinking without `re`? i'm curious

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `re.findall()`:

```
result = re.findall(r'var="(.*?)"', test)
print(result)  # ['this', 'that']
```

If the `test` string contains multiple lines, use the `re.DOTALL` flag.

```
re.findall(r'var="(.*?)"', test, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: This solution does not work if the string contains `\n`. How would this answer be adapted to support:

test = 'someth1 var="this \n then" someth2 var="that" '

Comment: @AlexFine if you need it to work over multiple lines, you need to set the [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag when doing your matching so that a dot matches new lines. You can pass the flag explicitly as: `re.findall(r'var="(.*?)"', test, re.DOTALL)`, or use in-line syntax within the pattern: `re.findall(r'(?s)var="(.*?)"', test)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current `regex` is that the capture group `(.*)` is an extremely greedy statement. After the first instance of a `var=` in your string, that capture group will get ***everything*** after it.

If you instead decrease the generalization of the expression to `var="(\w+)"`, you will not have the same issue, therefore changing that line of `python` to:

```
result = re.findall(r'var="([\w\s]+)"', test)
```

Comment: That will fail if the input string contains `var="foo bar"` (or any non-word character for that matter) under the assumption that he wants to extract everything between the quote marks.

Comment: @zwer yes, that may be true, but if the words within the quotes are being used as variables as per the `var=` prefix (an assumption that is probably not best to be made without OP specifying), the contents will never have a space

Comment: `\w` will capture numbers as well, and `3this` is not a valid variable name either.

Comment: Thanks for the specification, @zwer. Yes, in fact, I'd be interested in the general case when it could be `var="foo bar"`.

Comment: @Nonancourt ok, I'll make the revision now.

Comment: @zwer 's answer is just as appropriate, I'm simply not a proponent of using `.` because of greed in expressions