# extract string between two substrings in Haskell

Tags: regex, haskell, substring

I wanted to adapt the python regex (PCRE) technique in this SO question [Find string between two substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368969) to Haskell so that I can do the same in Haskell.

But I can't figure out how to make it work in GHC (8.2.1). I've installed `cabal install regex-pcre`, and came up with the following test code after some search:

```
import Text.Regex.PCRE
s = "+++asdf=5;iwantthis123jasd---"
result = (s ++ s) =~ "asdf=5;(.*)123jasd" :: [[String]]
```

I was hoping to get the first and last instance of the middle string

```
iwantthis
```

But I can't get the result right:

> [["asdf=5;iwantthis123jasd---+++asdf=5;iwantthis123jasd","iwantthis123jasd---+++asdf=5;iwantthis"]]

I haven't used regex or pcre in Haskell before.

*Can someone help with the right usage (to extract the first and last occurrence) ?
Also, I don't quite understand the `::[[String]]` usage here. What does it do and why is it necessary?*

I searched the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-pcre-0.94.4/docs/Text-Regex-PCRE-Wrap.html#v:-61--126--126-) but found no mention of the usage with type conversion to  `:: [[String]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result you obtain is the following:

```
Prelude Text.Regex.PCRE> (s ++ s) =~ "asdf=5;(.*)123jasd" :: [[String]]
[["asdf=5;iwantthis123jasd---+++asdf=5;iwantthis123jasd","iwantthis123jasd---+++asdf=5;iwantthis"]]
```

This is correct, the first element is the *implicit* capture group 0 (the entire regex), and the *second* element is that of capture group 1 (the one that matches `(.*)`. Since it matches like:

```
+++asdf=5;iwantthis123jasd---+++asdf=5;iwantthis123jasd---
```

So it still matches between the `asdf=5;` and `123jasd` part.

This is due to the fact that the Kleene start `*` matches *greedy*: it aims to capture as much as possible. You can use `(.*?)` however to use a *non-greedy* quantifier:

```
Prelude Text.Regex.PCRE> (s ++ s) =~ "asdf=5;(.*?)123jasd" :: [[String]]
[["asdf=5;iwantthis123jasd","iwantthis"],["asdf=5;iwantthis123jasd","iwantthis"]]
```

And now we obtain *two* matches. Each match has `"iwantthis"` as capture group 1.

You can use `map (head . tail)` or `map (!!1)` on it to obtain a list of captures of the `(.*?)` part:

```
Prelude Text.Regex.PCRE> map (!!1) ((s ++ s) =~ "asdf=5;(.*?)123jasd" :: [[String]])
["iwantthis","iwantthis"]
```

Comment: `map (!! 1)` might be more readable, because the number indicates the capture group.