# how to strip unwanted text from column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
 This is my DataFrame
                 Date         Value
0  "date": "1999-01-01  "s1":3.0000}
1  "date": "1999-01-02  "s1":3.0000}
2  "date": "1999-01-03  "s1":3.0000}
3  "date": "1999-01-04  "s1":3.0000}
4  "date": "1999-01-05  "s1":3.0000}

I want this DataFrame to be Transformed like this 

    Date             Value
    1999-01-01        3
    1999-01-02        3
    1999-01-03        3
    1999-01-04        3
    1999-01-05        3
    1999-01-06        3
```

I tried this

```
cols = ['Date', 'Value']
for col in cols:
    DataAll[col] = DataAll[col].map(lambda x: str(x).lstrip('{}').rstrip('"date:")({)(:)(s1)(})'))
```

Please if anyone has a solution for this Please help.
I have tied mny times for the solution and i didnt get any solution that has pure solution.

Comment: Your Pandas content appears to be broken JSON content.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Any chance you could fix it at the source?  Then, there most likely would be a more Pythonic way of parsing the JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain text methods first for strip `{}`, then split by `:`, select second lists and last remove trailing `"` and spaces:

```
cols = ['Date', 'Value']
f = lambda x: x.astype(str).str.strip('{}').str.split(':').str[1].str.strip(' "')
DataAll[cols] = DataAll[cols].apply(f)

print (DataAll)
         Date   Value
0  1999-01-01  3.0000
1  1999-01-02  3.0000
2  1999-01-03  3.0000
3  1999-01-04  3.0000
4  1999-01-05  3.0000
```

If jsons in column then first convert values to dictionaries in list comprehension and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
print (DataAll)
                             json_col
0  {"date": "1999-01-01","s1":3.0000}
1  {"date": "1999-01-02","s1":3.0000}
2  {"date": "1999-01-03","s1":3.0000}
3  {"date": "1999-01-04","s1":3.0000}
4  {"date": "1999-01-05","s1":3.0000}

import ast

DataAll1 = pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(x) for x in DataAll['json_col']])
print (DataAll1)
         date   s1
0  1999-01-01  3.0
1  1999-01-02  3.0
2  1999-01-03  3.0
3  1999-01-04  3.0
4  1999-01-05  3.0
```

Comment: list' object has no attribute 'str

Comment: @PavanSuvarna - answer was changed, please check now.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(("{"+df.agg('",'.join,axis=1)).apply(ast.literal_eval).tolist())` similar ,, but may be useful

Comment: what is ast module used for?

Comment: @nesinor - It is necessary for convert json strings to dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

You can just find the string between ':' and '.' as below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pan = pd.DataFrame({'date': ["1999-01-01", "1999-01-02","1999-01-03","1999-01-04","1999-01-05"], 'Value': ['"s1":3.0000', '"s1":3.0000', '"s1":3.0000', '"s1":3.0000', '"s1":3.0000']})

def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

for index, row in pan.iterrows():
    print(row['date'],find_between(row['Value'], ':', '.'))
```

find_between function will return the string between : and .

Function found at [Find string between two substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368969/find-string-between-two-substrings)