# Extract all substrings between two markers

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-re

I have a string:

```
mystr = "&marker1\nThe String that I want /\n&marker1\nAnother string that I want /\n"
```

What I want is a list of substrings between the markers `start="&maker1"` and `end="/\n"`. Thus, the expected result is:

```
whatIwant = ["The String that I want", "Another string that I want"]
```

I've read the answers here:

1. [Find string between two substrings [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368969/find-string-between-two-substrings)
2. [How to extract the substring between two markers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-the-substring-between-two-markers)

And tried this but not successfully,

```
>>> import re
>>> mystr = "&marker1\nThe String that I want /\n&marker1\nAnother string that I want /\n"
>>> whatIwant = re.search("&marker1(.*)/\n", mystr)
>>> whatIwant.group(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

What could I do to resolve this? Also, I have a very long string

```
>>> len(myactualstring)
7792818
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*What could I do to resolve this?*
I would do:

```
import re
mystr = "&marker1\nThe String that I want /\n&marker1\nAnother string that I want /\n"
found = re.findall(r"\&marker1\n(.*?)/\n", mystr)
print(found)
```

Output:

```
['The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ']
```

Note that:

- `&` has special meaning in `re` patterns, if you want literal & you need to escape it (`\&`)
- `.` does match anything except newlines
- `findall` is better suited choiced if you just want list of matched substrings, rather than `search`
- `*?` is non-greedy, in this case `.*` would work too, because `.` do not match newline, but in other cases you might ending matching more than you wish
- I used so-called raw-string (r-prefixed) to make escaping easier

Read module `re` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for discussion of raw-string usage and implicit list of characters with special meaning.

Comment: Is there a limit on the string length which can be process by regular expressions module?

Answer (score 2):

Consider this option using `re.findall`:

```
mystr = "&marker1\nThe String that I want /\n&marker1\nAnother string that I want /\n"
matches = re.findall(r'&marker1\n(.*?)\s*/\n', mystr)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['The String that I want', 'Another string that I want']
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
&marker1      match a marker
\n            newline
(.*?)         match AND capture all content until reaching the first
\s*           optional whitespace, followed by
/\n           / and newline
```

Note that `re.findall` will only capture what appears in the `(...)` capture group, which is what you are trying to extract.