# Extract all substrings between two markers for a very long string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-re

This is a continuation of the question [Extract all substrings between two markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62342552/extract-all-substrings-between-two-markers). The [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62342651/4782513) by @Daweo and @Tim Biegeleisen works for small strings.

But for very large strings regular expressions doesn't seem to work. This could be because of a of a limit on string length as seen below:

```
>>> import re
>>> teststr = "&marker1\nThe String that I want /\n&marker1\nAnother string that I want /\n"
>>> for i in range(0, 23):
...    teststr += teststr # creating a very long string here
... 
>>> len(teststr)
603979776
>>> found = re.findall(r"\&marker1\n(.*?)/\n", newstr)
>>> len(found)
46
>>> found
['The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ', 'The String that I want ', 'Another string that I want ']
```

What could I do to resolve this and find all occurrences between the makers `start="&maker1"` and `end="/\n"` ? What is the maximum string length that `re` can handle?

Comment: Works on my machine, at least when I replaced `newstr` by `teststr`.

Comment: @Ronald The question has been edited. Does it still work?

Comment: It works on my home machine, with Python 3.8.3. `len(found)` is printed as `16777216`.

Comment: Still works ;-) I suppose pushing it to the limits depends on the memory of your system? But what is the error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get `re.findall` to work. Now I do use `re` but to find the location of markers and extract the substrings manually.

```
locs_start = [match.start() for match in re.finditer("\&marker1", mylongstring)]
locs_end = [match.start() for match in re.finditer("/\n", mylongstring)]

substrings = []
for i in range(0, len(locs_start)):
    substrings.append(mylongstring[locs_start[i]:locs_end[i]+1])
```