# How to extract strings between two markers for each object of a list in python

Tags: python, string, list, extract

I got a list of strings. Those strings have all the two markers in. I would love to extract the string between those two markers for each string in that list.

example:

```
markers 'XXX' and 'YYY' --> therefore i want to extract 78665786 and 6866 

['XXX78665786YYYjajk', 'XXX6866YYYz6767'....]
```

Comment: You can apply string slicing: `[s[s.index('XXX') + 3: s.index('YYY')] for s in lst]`. Or using [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search): `[re.search("XXX(.*)YYY", s).group(1) for s in lst]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is the +3: standing for ?

Comment: `3` is the length of `'XXX'` string, so we need to add it to not include `XXX` in result.

Comment: ok. and we can ignore the length of YYY ?

Comment: Yes, `str.index()` returns index of **first char in substring**.

Comment: i used that code for my exampe. i got following syntax: ValueError: substring not found.

Comment: It means that one (?) of strings doesn't contain either `"XXX"` or `"YYY"`.

Comment: import re
x=['ATGCCAGCTTATTCAACCTCCGTATAATAGTGCTGTACTAAGCAAATTTATAGTTCTCTAGAAAGTGCCCGCGGTTATTCGGTGCAGTCTGGATCGGAAAG', 'ATGCCAGCTTATTCAACCACAACCACCATCAATGACAACAATCTCCAAGCACACTAGACGATCGCTTTCTGGGGTTATTCGGTGCAGTTAGATCGGAAGAG']




output = []
for item in x:
    output.append(re.search('ATGCCAGCTTATTCAACC(.*)GGTTATTCGGTGCAGTCT', item).group(1))

print(output)

Comment: Are you sure that all items will match provided pattern?

Comment: i got in both strings the two markers 'ATGCCAGC....' and 'GGTTATTC...'

Comment: No, error message says that at least one of string isn't match.

Answer (score 2):

You can just loop over your list and [grab the substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368969/find-string-between-two-substrings). You can do something like:

```
import re

my_list = ['XXX78665786YYYjajk', 'XXX6866YYYz6767']
output = []
for item in my_list:
    output.append(re.search('XXX(.*)YYY', item).group(1))

print(output)
```

Output:

```
['78665786', '6866']
```

Comment: i got following --> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @derpaminontas_1992, it means that there's no match of pattern in string, so it returned `None`.

Comment: @derpaminontas_1992 Could you comment what you've written? As long as your expression and your strings contain the same pattern, it should find your substring.

Comment: i found the mistake. my list after the following  code contains two strings that dont have forw_primer and rev_primer in fasta_files: 
match=[p for p in fasta_file if forw_primer and rev_primer in p]

the problem is that i dont know why i got those two more sequences that dont have the marker in.

Comment: Use try and except. Make sure to log exactly what wasn't as expected and check that with your dataset and wherever you're getting that data from.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
l = ['XXX78665786YYYjajk', 'XXX6866YYYz6767'....]
l = [re.search(r'XXX(.*)YYY', i).group(1) for i in l]
```

This should work

Comment: i got that for my example here --> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Can you paste here the list you are operating with. This error is result of absence of given pattern, i.e. 'XXX{some string}YYY'.

Comment: i found the mistake. my list after the following code contains two strings that dont have forw_primer and rev_primer in fasta_files: match=[p for p in fasta_file if forw_primer and rev_primer in p] the problem is that i dont know why i got those two more sequences that dont have the marker in

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be:

```
import re
test_string=['XXX78665786YYYjajk','XXX78665783336YYYjajk']
int_val=[int(re.search(r'\d+', x).group()) for x in test_string]
```

Comment: It's definitely not the best regex patter you can use for this, there're too many cases where it can fail.

Answer (score -1):

the command **split()**  splits a String into different parts.

```
list1 = ['XXX78665786YYYjajk', 'XXX6866YYYz6767']
list2 = []

for i in list1:
    d = i.split("XXX")
    for g in d:
        d = g.split("YYY")
        list2.append(d)

print(list2)
```

it's saved into a list