# Removing Java Script from HTML Python

Tags: python

I'm having an issue removing Java Script from HTML. I have put the contents of the HTML into a list and I am wanting to remove any text that is between the `<script>` and `</script>` tags. Note that a `<script>` (or `</script>`) tag can have any amounts of whitespace or other text between the `<script` (or `</script`) portion and the final `>` character and valid script tag that must be removed.

So far I have this and it only seems to be removing the `<script>`. BTW I am wanting to do this without loading a package.

Thanks in advance.

```
def clean_JS(full_lists):
    indx = 0
    html = ''
    clean_lists = full_lists
    for i in range(len(clean_lists)):
        html_full = clean_lists[i][2]
        while True:
            idx1 = html_full.find('<script', indx)
            if idx1 == -1:
                break
            idx2 = html_full.find('>', idx1 + 1)
            if idx2 == -1:
                break
            idx3 = html_full.find('</script', idx2 + 1)
            if idx3 == -1:
                break
            idx4 = html_full.find('>', idx3 + 1)
            if idx4 == -1:
                break
            html += html_full[indx: idx1]
            indx = idx4 + 1
        html += html_full[indx:]
        clean_lists[i][2] = html

    return (html)
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] ? Could you also provide an example of the HTML file you are trying to parse? Is there a reason why you don't want to use an existing module? Because you are trying to develop code that will take time that would be better spent using a robust existing library. For example, take a look at [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend importing the [Regular expression operations library (re)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to find the text between the substrings `<script>` and `</script>` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368969/find-string-between-two-substrings).

However, if you do not want to load a package, you need to do a few workarounds, as in this example:

```
before_script = html_full.split('<script>')[0] # Getting whatever comes before the script
after_script = html_full.split('</script>')[1] # Getting whatever comes after the script
clean_html = before_script + after_script # Adding what comes before with what comes after
```

This works assuming you only have one script in your HTML file. if you have more, you could drop the empty values from the before_script and after_script lists, and add the pairs together.