# Split a string in Python dictionary with two different separators only if the separator exist on the string

Tags: python, string, dictionary, split, txt

I have a dictionary :

```
{'...': '...',
'unite_fonctionnelle': 'text to keeep',
'...': '...'}
```

In this case the dictionary is good but sometimes the value of `unite_fonctionnelle` need to be cleaned, the syntaxe is always the same:

```
{'...': '...',
'unite_fonctionnelle' : 'asjbzjqnfknqfsnf<Run>text to keeep</Run>qsdqsdqsdqsfqsfegdhfkdnh',
'...': '...'}
```

I want to transform the value of `unite_fonctionnelle` when tags `<Run>` and `</Run>` are present in the string to keep only the text between the two tags. How can I do this with split() ?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368969/find-string-between-two-substrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use regex here.

Try this :

```
import re

for key, value in dic.items():
    if '<Run>' in str(value):
        output = re.search('<Run>(.*)</Run>', str(value))
        print(output.group(1))
```

Comment: Thanks, I adapt it to my code and it works perfectly!

Comment: Welcome :) @Howins

Answer (score 1):

Given `d` your dictionary:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    if '<Run>' in v:
        d[k] = v.split('<Run>')[1].split('</Run>')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach.

```
import re
dic = {
'unite_fonctionnelle' : 'asjbzjqnfknqfsnf<Run>text to keeep</Run>qsdqsdqsdqsfqsfegdhfkdnh'
}
for key,val in dic.items():
    if(all(x in val for x in ['<Run>','</Run>'])):dic[key] = re.split('<Run>|</Run>',val)[1]
```