# How to make a print("{}") with another File?

Tags: python, file, compiler-errors

I want to make the `print({})` display something from another
File. What I have been trying:

main.py:

```py
with open("Filename.txt", "tr") as f:
  data = f.readlines()
 if "print({})" in data:
  print("{}".format(data))
```

Filename.txt:

`print("Hello world")`

result:

This means I have made an error. But there were no error messages. What did I do wrong?

Comment: The file doesn't contain the exact string `print({})`, so the `if` statement isn't entered. It isn't clear what you want it to do instead.

Comment: `if "print({})" in data:` doesn't do what you think it does. You are clearly expecting it to match any call to the `print()` function. But `in` doesn't  do that. I think you are reaching for a regular expression match. Look at the `re` module, specifically `re.search()`. Be aware that for beginners `re`'s learning curve is a bit steep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will search for the exact string `print({})`. It seems like you need the text within that print statement, its better to use regex and find text between `print(` and `)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3369000/7334699

I don't know what your goal exactly is, but you can also take a look at the `eval()` function which just runs python code within a string.

Comment: I am making a Programming language in python. Thanks!