# Discord.py - Handling user to mentioning other users

Tags: python, discord.py

#### My Goals

When the user tried to use the command but mentioning a other members, it will sends an errors to the users.

#### MY Current Codes

```
@bot.command()
async def tell(ctx, *, text):
    if text in ctx.guild.members:
       await ctx.send("Mentioning other's members not allowed")
       return
```

Comment: so when the tell bot command is run you want to check if the user is mentioning another user in the text?

Comment: yeah something like that

Comment: well in discord you mention others using @name. so scan the text using regex for that pattern. something like this regex `^@[a-zA-Z]*` if it finds something then there is a mention in the text. additionally, i think in the text for a mention it will have the mention like so @name#1234 so you may want to improve on that regex for more accurate matching

Comment: [site](https://regexr.com/) to help you build and test that regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to tackle this, and here I will show you two possible methods that may interest you. The **first method** is, as [Anu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12201376/anu) said, to use [Regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). You can check if anything starts with `<@` and ends with `>`, as this is how most user *and* role mentions are laid out, and this is how the bot sees mentions. The **second method** is not as good as using regex, where you check if the [`ctx.message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message) has any mentions in it via [`message.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.mentions). Do view both of these methods and some further explanation below.

```py
# Method 1: Recommended and Regex
# Checks if 'tell' has mentions via regex
# I will link other questions on regex below to help you
import re # Don't forget to import this!

@bot.command()
async def tell(ctx, *, tell):
    x = re.search('<@(.*)>', tell)
    # User mentions are usually in the form of
    # <@USERID> or <@!USERID>
    if not x:
        await ctx.send(tell)
        return
    await ctx.send("Don't mention other users")


# Method 2: Not recommended but working
# Check if the original command message has mentions in it via message.mentions
# Will backfire if the user uses a mention prefix (@Bot tell)
@bot.command()
async def tell(ctx, *, text):
    if ctx.message.mentions:
        await ctx.send("Mentioning other's members not allowed")
        return
    await ctx.send(text)
```

[Image for Method 1]

[image: Working Method 1]

[Image for Method 2]

[image: Working Method 2]

[Image for how Bots see mentions (id blocked for privacy reasons)]

[image: How bots see mentions]

**Other links**:

- [Find string between two substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368969/find-string-between-two-substrings) - SO
- [Python Regex](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) - W3Schools
- [Discord.py Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message)