# Get words between specific words in a Python string

Tags: python

I'm working on getting the words between certain words in a string.

[Find string between two substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368969/find-string-between-two-substrings) Referring to this article, I succeeded in catching words in the following way.

```
s = 'asdf=5;iwantthis123jasd'
result = re.search('asdf=5;(.*)123jasd', s)
print(result.group(1))
```

But in the sentence below it failed.

```
s = '''        <div class="prod-origin-price ">
        <span class="discount-rate">
            4%
        </span>
            <span class="origin-price">'''


result = re.search('<span class="discount-rate">(.*)</span>', s)
print(result.group(1))
```

I'm trying to bring '4%'. Everything else succeeds, but I don't know why only this one fails.
Help

Comment: If you have a lot of information like this, you may want to look into my answer, rather than treating everything like strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (mind the white spaces and new lines)

```
import re
s = '''        <div class="prod-origin-price ">
        <span class="discount-rate">
            4%
        </span>
            <span class="origin-price">'''


result = re.search('<span class="discount-rate">\s*(.*)\s*</span>', s)
print(result.group(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use re.DOTALL flag for matching new lines:

```py
result = re.search('<span class="discount-rate">(.*)</span>', s, re.DOTALL)
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 1):

This is structured data, not just a string, so we can use a library like [Beautiful Soup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to help us simplify such tasks:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = '''        <div class="prod-origin-price ">
        <span class="discount-rate">
            4%
        </span>
            <span class="origin-price">'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
value = soup.find(class_='discount-rate').get_text(strip=True)
print(value)

# Output:
4%
```